# Deprecated data when getting longtext from mysql. (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php to retrieve long text files from a mysql database. These files are pdfs encoded into base64 strings. The strings work perfectly fine in the database and produce the pdf I desire, but when I retrieve the data through php there is always a large block of characters missing in the middle of the string.

I've tried this with multiple different strings and it keeps giving me the same result, a large block of characters missing in the middle of the string. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I'm using, my mistake. At the moment I'm just printing the string onto the screen.

```
    <?php

// Make sure an ID was passed
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Get the ID
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);

    // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
    if($id <= 0) {
        die('The ID is invalid!');
    }
    else {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('***', '***', '***', '***');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Fetch the file information
        $query = "SELECT name, data FROM report_storage WHERE `id` = {$id}";
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        if($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                // Print headers


                // Print data
                $data = $row['data'];

                //echo strlen($data);
                echo $data;
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
            }

            // Free the mysqli resources
            @mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        @mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
}
?>
```

Comment: *"a large block of characters **missing** in the middle of the string"* --- Missing **"code"** too. ;-) Waiting on the ***"Here is my code:"...*** part.

Comment: What do you expect us to do with no code?

Comment: You'll need to post some code to help get your question answered...we can't do much without that.

Comment: Sorry new to this site, I added the code now.

Comment: Then there might be a column that contains a blank field, have you checked for that? @user3166937 We'd need for you to also give us an example of blank line, if possible, taken from an HTML output or `print_r` results.

Comment: Or, it might have something to do with the PDF creation method itself, which is not shown nor explained. @user3166937

Comment: There aren't any blank fields in the database, just checked. Copying an example might not be practical since it's about 50 pages long. It basically looks like this: data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyA(Large space)ASDFWR34asdf

Comment: Hmm I don't think it has to do with the PDF creation method because if I go into my database where the data strings are and I copy paste that string into my browser, it looks exactly like it's supposed too. It's when I'm getting the data from the database using php that the data string messes up somewhere...

Comment: Well then, you need to look in your creation code where it is happening, which doesn't seem to be posted here. `data:application/pdf;base64,(look between here =>)JVBERi0xLjMKMyA(Large space)(<= and here)ASDFWR34asdf` this doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you posted for code.